# Wowza Engine Livestream Events / or iOS Video Events

Tags: ios, wowza

When using Wowza Streaming Engine is there a way to fire an event when a broadcast (from say GoCoder) start and end? I guess the question is, if I'm trying to connect to an m3u8 file before or after it starts, how do I determine that it's started or ended without polling regularly? Or should Livestream events be handled by Objective-C?

Just looking for a starting point.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Found that the easiest was was to poll for the existence of a playlist file.